# When $2$-cycles (transpositions) are not disjoint, they don't necessarily commute?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Consider a permutation that can be written as a product of $2$-cycles,
for instance:
$$
(1632)(457)=(12)(13)(16)(47)(45)
$$

The $2$-cycles on the right-hand side of the identity above don't necessarily commute, correct? Since they are not disjoint.

Comment: Try it out.  Compute $(12)(23)$ and $(23)(12)$.

Comment: Non-disjoint two-cycles will *never* commute.

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, I understand the computation, but is there an example where they might commute, and if they can't how could you prove it in general?

Comment: No, they'll never commute.  Look at Bernard's answer.  Note that if $a=b$ then you don't have two two-cycles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(a\,b)(b\,c)=(a\,b\,c),\qquad (b\,c)(a\,b)=(a\,c\,b)=(a\,b\,c)^{-1}$.